# [Clean Code]: Which is better? Variable or return one-line function?

Tags: actionscript-3, coding-style

Which is better? One-line returning function `optionIsOutOfRange()`:

```
    public function deleteOption(index:int):void {
        if (optionIsOutOfRange(index)) {
            throw new Error("Option index is out of range! Cannot delete!");
        } else {
            options.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    private function optionIsOutOfRange(optionIndex:int):Boolean {
        return optionIndex > numOptions - 1;
    }
```

or variable here is `optionIsOutOfRange`:

```
    public function deleteOption(index:int):void {
        var optionIsOutOfRange:Boolean = index > numOptions - 1;
        if (optionIsOutOfRange(index)) {
            throw new Error("Option index is out of range! Cannot delete!");
        } else {
            options.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Neither is better, do whichever you prefer.

Comment: what about index < 0?

Comment: No offense but I'll add it if someone is stupid enough to pass a number that is below 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is needed if you want to implement some checking logic that is used in multiple places and could change in the future.

For code maintainability and scalability a function is better, for performance an inline code is better.